# Dexie.js: get failures data records in bulkAdd() error catch

Tags: node.js, indexeddb, dexie

If I add a blob to my database using bulkAdd(), then if any key already exist then it throw error saying same.

```
bulkAdd(): 127 of 127 operations failed. 
Errors: ConstraintError: Key already exists in the object store.
```

Now I want, if any key already exist in database then update data associated with that key using some if condition (e.g. if it is smaller than 1).
But when I try to console.log(error.failures) it just shows messages not the data object.
Can any one tell me how we can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`Table.bulkAdd()`](https://dexie.org/docs/Table/Table.bulkAdd()) the operation will fail if there is a primary key that already exists.

> ### Table.add()
>
> Adds an object to the object store.
>
> #### [Remarks](https://dexie.org/docs/Table/Table.add()#remarks)
>
> Add given object to store. If an object with the same primary key already exist, the operation will fail and returned promise [catch()](https://dexie.org/docs/Promise/Promise.catch()) callback will be called with the error object.

You can use [`Table.bulkPut()`](https://dexie.org/docs/Table/Table.bulkPut()) for replacing records in a case of duplicate keys.

> ### Table.put()
>
> Adds new or replaces existing object in the object store.
>
> #### [Remarks](https://dexie.org/docs/Table/Table.put()#remarks)
>
> If an object with the same primary key already exists, it will be replaced with the given object. If it does not exist, it will be added.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**table.bulkPut()**](https://dexie.org/docs/Table/Table.bulkPut()).

It adds element if the key is not available. If available, update value. Also it is faster.